# Show image of product by browsing select2 options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-select2

I have the latest version of select2 collection of products, and i want to show the image of the product on a single img tag dynamically according to my select2 cursor while I'm browsing for the product so I can make sure that the product i'm about to choose is the right product since some product have a similiar name.

My select2 options is based on the chosen customer ny onchange using ajax

so far I tried to use 'on' and select2:selecting listener, and it's not working.

here's my progress:

the html:

```
<select type="text" class="js-example-basic-single"
    style="width: 100%" id="search" onchange="toCart()">
</select>
```

the JQuery:

```
$('#search').on('select2:selecting', function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

If you find my question is vague, please kindly leave a comment so I can improve my question. thank you.

Comment: you didn't show the select options.. and you said `I want to show the image of the product on a single img tag dynamically`. Where does the image of the product come from? by the way the correct css selector to get the selected option is: `#search option:selected` but you don't need it because the change event will be handled by toCart() ... it would be better to use `toCart(event)` .. anyway I'll write a partial answer to better show the concept but I'll need you to be more clear about the whole problem to better fit the solution

Comment: Oh right, I'm sorry, My select2 options is based on the chosen customer by onchange using ajax. I guess your suggestion is what I'm looking for, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds for me like you are looking for a way to get the highlighted option text and value from the select2 dropdown menu.

The selecting event is not made for this. It is fired just before you select something, in the moment you click on it or press enter.

select2 doesn't provide a "highlight/hover"-event and getting the highlighted field requires you to use the [capture-event-phase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/eventPhase) or a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) if you don't want to modify it.

Here is an example with the capture events:

```js
$('#example').select2()
  .on("select2:opening", () => ($(img).show(), onHighlight()))
  .on("select2:closing", () => ($(img).hide(), onHighlight()));

function onHighlight(event) {
  /*
     both events are stopped at the element to prevent the
     page from scrolling when using arrow keys from within 
     the search field

     this means, the capture phase is required and since the 
     dropdown is not build when the event triggers, you have
     to wait for a short moment with setTimeout or 
     requestAnimationFrame
   */
  setTimeout(() => {
    // only for the "#example" select2
    const el = document.querySelector(`[id^="select2-example-"].select2-results__option--highlighted`);
    if (el) {
      // depending on the id of the original select, the value to slice differs
      const value = el.id.split("-").slice(4).join("-"),
        text = el.innerText;
      // set the image matching the text and value
      img.src = `https://dummyimage.com/300x100/000/ffffff?text=value:${value}+text:${text}`;
      console.log(value, text);
    }
  });
}
document.body.addEventListener("mouseenter", onHighlight, true);
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", onHighlight, true);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%;">
    <option value=0>January</option>
    <option value=1>February</option>
    <option value=2>March</option>
    <option value=3>April</option>
    <option value=4>May</option>
    <option value="Än Êxámplè">Foobar</option>
</select>
<img id="img" style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: auto; right: 0; display: none; z-index: 1234">
```

Comment: what if i want to show the value of a data atrribute? for example data-pict="logo.png"? so far i tried using el.getAttribute('data-pict') and failed

Comment: @YusufGiovanno there is no straight reference from the li element to the original select option fields. But you could get it with something like: ``document.querySelector(`#example option[value="${value.replace(/"/g,'\\$&')}"`).dataset.pict``. But make sure, that you have no duplicated value in the select.

Answer (score 0):

The [select2](/questions/tagged/select2) events do not appear to cater for your scenario.

The `select2:selecting` event is a "pre-select" - ie the user has selected an element and the event allows your code to cancel that selection.

With the `templateResult` templating built-in to [select2](/questions/tagged/select2), you can create any DOM in the drop down and thus apply events to those DOM elements.

---

Unfortunately, as noted in the comments, each select2 `li` has some padding/border that means using an event on the inner (templated) element will not trigger on the *whole* of the `li`, even with some mitigation such as setting 100% width.

Instead, you can listen on `.select2-results__option`

---

Then you just need to add enough information to the inner templated html so that you can create your preview.  Here's an example using the original `<option>` `value=`:

```js
$('.select2').select2({
  templateResult: template
});

function template(state) {
  if (!state.id) {
    return state.text;
  }
  var $state = $(`<span class='mySelect2Option' data-value='${state.element.value}'>` +
    state.element.text +
    "</span>");
  return $state;
}

$(document).on("mouseenter", ".select2-results__options>.select2-results__option", function() {
  var option = $(this).find(".mySelect2Option");
  $("#preview").text(option.data("value"))
});
```

```css
#preview {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5em; /* so not hidden by [result] */
  width: 2em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div id='preview'></div>
<select class="select2">
  <option value="AL">Alabama (longer entry)</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I thought of the `templateResult()` callback at first too, but it fails on some situations. It doesn't support the arrow keys at all. And you have to use the full width of the container, otherwise you won't trigger the `mouseenter` behind or before the span - with this you are forced to hover the text.